# BigQuery hide UDF implementation

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery routines have these permissions as per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control):

- bigquery.routines.create   Create new routines (functions and stored procedures).
- bigquery.routines.delete   Delete routines.
- bigquery.routines.get        Get routine definitions and metadata.
- bigquery.routines.list       List routines and metadata on routines.
- bigquery.routines.update    Update routine definitions and metadata.

Is it possible for a service account to be given permission to only be able to execute a UDF (within a sql query) without getting "bigquery.routines.get" permission i.e. not see the UDF definition?

Basically I have an obfuscation function as below, which I apply on sensitive data in table columns, and I want to hide the salt value inside it, therefore hide the whole implementation of obfuscation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `project`.dataset.get_obfuscated_val(s ANY TYPE) AS (sha256(concat(cast(s as String),'my-secret-salt-value')));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no execute-only permission on BigQuery routines. Although there is an indirect approach to do execute-only, you need to be aware of that, user that calls the function is still able to reverse engineering from the query plan to guess what the function body is.

With that being said, the indirect approach is to define an [authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views). User are granted permission to access the authorized view but not the function backing the view. Therefore, this authorized view acts like an execute-only permission to the function (that you want to hide).

Comment: Hi Yun Zhang, I have added extra information and given the UDF definition and why I'm trying to hide. If the UDF is within a view, not sure if we can pass the parameter of the data to be obfuscated.